# My previously working library returns a weird Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') on NextJS 14 Update

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a NextJS project was running NextJS 12 and I have my own library that I have imported locally for dev work, this library contains some helper functions and re-usable components that I can use in all of my projects.

This works fine in NextJS 12 but have tried upgrading NextJS 13 and then I hit this error where if I include a component from the library, I get the `Cannot read properties of null (reading` useState`)`

As a test, I created a brand new NextJS project (although this time its 14) with a brand new library.

I create a function in the library and use in my new test project and it works perfectly fine.

I add a component to the library and import it into my test project, no errors or warnings but then when I run it I get the below (same error as above in more details)

[image: error using component in test project on NextJS 14]

My NextJS project `package.json` is below:

```json
{
  "name": "new-nextjs-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "new-nextjs-library": "file:../new-nextjs-library",
    "next": "13.5.6",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` is below:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    },
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My test library `package.json` is below:

```json
{
  "name": "new-nextjs-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "/dist"
  ],
  "script": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

My library `tsconfig.json` is below:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    //"target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom"],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2018",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

In my `src/classes` folder I have a file called `sayHello` which includes the following code which works fine in my main test project

```js
export const sayHello = (firstName: string, lastName: string) => {
    return `${firstName} ${lastName}`
}
```

My component in my library is below, this is located in `/src/components`

```js
"use client"

import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Clicker = () => {

    const [clickCount, setClickCount] = useState(0);

    return (
        <>
            <button type='button' onClick={() => setClickCount(prev => prev++)}>
                Click
            </button>
            <p>
                You've clicked {clickCount}
            </p>
        </>
    )
}

export default Clicker
```

Note I tried adding use client at the top in case it was something to do with server side components in the new NextJS but doesn't make any difference

My library `index.ts` file is below:

```js
import React from "react";
//Components
import Clicker from "./components/Clicker";

//Classes
import {sayHello} from "./classes/sayHello";

export {
    Clicker,
    sayHello
}
```

I'm importing the component and using it in my main app as below

```js
import React from "react";
import {NextPage} from "next";
import {Clicker, sayHello} from "new-nextjs-library";


const HomePage : NextPage = () => {

  return (
      <>
        <h1>My New Page</h1>

          <p>Hello {sayHello("Chris", "Board")}</p>
          <Clicker />
      </>
  )
}

export default HomePage;
```

In the browser console I see the following (added as an image as it didn't format very nicely

[image: browser console errors]

How am I doing an invalid hook, the only hook I'm using is the `useState` within the functional component is valid

How can I get this:

> cannot read properties of null reading `useState`.

This makes no sense, and I say this approach has worked on NextJS, but NextJS 13 or 14 I hit this problem.

Comment: In your library's `package.json`, can you try and list `React` as a peer dependency instead of a dev dependency? That would make sure your library will use the React version from the main project, not a separate instance. And see that `useState` is imported correctly from React in your library component: `import React, { useState } from 'react';`/

Comment: No luck unfortunately, still same issue

Comment: Your clicker won't work as you expect.  `prev++` is a post-evaluation operator.  Use `prev+1` for clarity (since `++` tends to indicate a side effect) or if you insist `++prev`

Comment: I was able to get your code to run as you have it architectured, but I used the default configs rather than copying yours.

Comment: @possum when you say got it to work, in a library. If I move the component into the main NextJS app it works. I’m not fixed if the clicker component doesn’t work it just a test component to prove I can render a component from the library.

How do you do defaults as not sure if it’s the way I create the library but there is no defaults as such as I create the package.json and tsconfig files manually. Is there a more better way to start a library project than just manually create the project structure

Comment: Yes, as a library.  I didn't change the structure.  I did a new nextjs 14 install, did a basic `npm init` in the library directory and export that index file, added the relevant packages to both.  The rest was copy/paste your code.  `npm init` creates a default `package.json`.  There's stock tsconfigs available https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tsconfig/recommended

Comment: Well in that case I'm even more confused. I pretty much did that as well, to create this test library and no matter what I try get the same problem. The only difference was I copied my tsconfig from my previous library as initially I was expecting the issue was caused by a different package causing the library to break, but getting this issue on a blank library pretty much so I'm at a complete loss now, if I use NextJs 12 it works, so don't understand why when I use NextJS 14 hit the problem

Comment: I’ve tried tried using Rollup as a bundle instead of just doing a basic tsc to compile in the hope that makes a difference but that causes the exact same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured the problem.

I had to change my next.config.js file to be called next.config.mjs.

I then had to add the following to this file:

```
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    config.resolve.alias["react"] = path.resolve("./node_modules/react");
    return config;
  }
```

The complete file looks like the below

```
import path from "path";

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,

  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    config.resolve.alias["react"] = path.resolve("./node_modules/react");
    return config;
  }
};

export default nextConfig;
```

I'm not entirely sure why I have to do this now, npm list react only showed one version of react in the project but as soon as this section was added to the next config and restarted, the library started working again.

Comment: I believe using workspaces, listing react as a peer dep for your lib, and then using your libs name instead of `file:..` in the dependent next.js app would have resolved your issue without needing the webpack alias.